# How to properly override the style defined for the media query before the current one?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This is a header for small devices:

[image]

and this is the CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #393939;
    font-family: 'Molengo','Verdana','Georgia','Times New Roman',serif;

}

a, a:visited {
    color: #F03366;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#div-header{
    height: 3.1em;
    background-color: #393939;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px ;
}

#div-header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

#div-header h1 a, #div-header h1 a:visited {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#div-header .links{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 4.5em;
}

#div-header .links li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#div-header .links li a {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnh2E/

this is the header for larger screens:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    #div-header{
        height: 3.1em;
        background-color: #393939;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
        padding: 10px 30px;
    }

    #div-header h1 {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    #div-header h1 a, #div-header h1 a:visited {
        color: #DDDDDD;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #div-header .links {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        /*padding-top: 1em; */
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #div-header .links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 7px;
    }

    #div-header .links li a {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8pzX/

The most important portion of code that differs between both
pages, is the one for the ***.links*** class.

base css

```
#div-header .links{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 4.5em;
}
```

css for big screens

```
#div-header .links {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now, I used media query to make a responsive design.

Here you can find the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5v8YE/

The first problem is that the css for big screens inherits some attributes of the base css, like the text-align and the margin top.

So I rewrite the style this way:

```
#div-header .links {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

But now the header looks like this:

[image]

If I add this line:

```
padding-top: 1em;
```

the header looks fine again, but Do you know why the re written code
is not working even when I restored it to the default values for the big
screen?

Besides, is there a way to tell a media query to complety overwrite the style
defined in the media query before the current one?

I hope I explained myself clearly. I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting the margin within the CSS for big screens. Take that line out and the rest should work.

```
#div-header .links {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The cascading nature of CSS means that you can't just clear an existing set of styles, they need to be overwritten. So you maintain the styles you need and overwrite the ones to make a page responsive.

Comment: if I remove margin: 0; then the css for that class will have the margin defined in the base css: margin-top: 4.5em;. I did that to reset the margin to the default value. Is there a better way to reset the margin?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. If adding the padding-top shows the correct display then go with that. As stated above, its just the way CSS is, you can't just clear a style definition, you need to override it.

Comment: Or instead of overriding it, you can also limit that particular style with a different query. For example @media (max-width: 1199px) Choose what's best for you (if this works for you).

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code a bit and make some clean on useless definition.

I use the display table and table-cell to center the li and the h1.

```
#div-header{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#div-header .links {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can see the new code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5v8YE/4/